# R function to compute deviation matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, functional-programming

I've writen a function to compute a matrix where each column is the corresponding input matrix column minus the column mean.

```
# compute the deviation matrix
deviation <- function(X) {
  one <- rep(1, nrow(X))
  n <- ncol(X)
  d <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = ncol(X))
  for(i in seq.int(from = 1, to = n)) {
    d[,i] <- X[,i] - mean(X[,i], na.rm = TRUE) * one
  }
  d
}
```

Could this function be written more idiomatically in R (using functional programming, perhaps)?

Comment: Thanks, good catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sweep` and `colMeans`:

```
sweep(mat, 2, colMeans(mat))
```

By default, `sweep` uses `-` or the subtraction function, taking the column means as calculated by `colMeans`, from the values in each column (`MARGIN=2`). Gives the same result:

```
mat <- matrix(1:12,nrow=3)
deviation(mat)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    1    1    1

sweep(mat, 2, colMeans(mat))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Or `mat-colMeans(mat)[col(mat)]`